# Why flutter debug works but not release?

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

My app builds successfully in debug mode and runs fine but when using flutter run --release it gives some issues.

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run w
ith --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s


Exception: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.
```

My flutter version is:

```
Framework • revision f04b3d917f (7 months ago) • 2020-11-07 16:09:02 -0500
Engine • revision 0f7cdca65f
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-27.0.dev)
```